# Using a combination of block storage and object storage for serving photos. Good idea?

Tags: database-design

I have a real estate app and I need to create a database for listing photos.  These photos will be actively accessed by users.

The full-size photos are about 50-70KB in size.  I will create thumbnails for the first photo of each listing, which will be about 20KB.

Here's my plan:

1. Store thumbnail photos directly on server (block storage), for faster access
2. Store all the full sized photos in object storage

Is this a good optimization idea?  Am I adding unnecessary complexity?  Should I simply store all photos in object storage?

Answer (score 0):

The problem with block storage is that you loose all the benefits of integrity constraints - photos will get forgotten when listings are deleted etc...

Block storage is likely to be faster and is easier to diversify if there are speed problems,  so your trade-off is speed and scalability vs ease of development and management.

Comment: Thanks for that.  To follow up on your response.  In terms of serving thumbnail photos (10-20 KB in size).  Would it be *much* faster to serve them from an SSD block storage, as opposed to serving them from an object storage?  If the speed difference is minimal, I may as well keep everything in object storage.

Comment: the speed difference will probably be minimal, database indices are more heavily optimized than file-system directories, so what performance you lose by storing a file inside another file you get back by locating it more efficiently.